# Avoiding quantifiers in Z3

Tags: z3, smt, theorem-proving

I am experimenting with Z3 where I combine the theories of arithmetic, quantifiers and equality. This does not seem to be very efficient, in fact it seems to be more efficient to replace the quantifiers with all instantiated ground instances when possible. Consider the following example, in which I have encoded the unique names axiom for a function `f` that takes two arguments of sort `Obj` and returns an interpreted sort `S`. This axiom states that each unique list of arguments to `f` returns a unique object:

```
(declare-datatypes () ((Obj o1 o2 o3 o4 o5 o6 o7 o8)))
(declare-sort S 0)

(declare-fun f (Obj Obj) S)
(assert (forall ((o11 Obj) (o12 Obj) (o21 Obj) (o22 Obj))
    (=> 
        (not (and (= o11 o21) (= o12 o22)))
        (not (= (f o11 o12) (f o21 o22))))))
```

Although this is a standard way of defining such an axiom in logic, implementing it like this is computationally very expensive. It contains 4 quantified variables, which each can have 8 values. This means that this results in `8^4 = 4096` equalities. It takes Z3 0.69s and 2016 quantifier instantiations to prove this. When I write a simple script that generates the instances of this formula:

```
(assert (distinct (f o1 o1) (f o1 o2) .... (f o8 o7) (f o8 o8)))
```

It takes 0.002s to generate these axioms, and another 0.01s (or less) to prove it in Z3. When we increase the objects in the domain, or the number of arguments to the function `f` this different increases rapidly, and the quantified case quickly becomes unfeasible.

This makes me wonder: when we have a bounded domain, why would we use quantifiers in Z3 in the first place? I know that SMT uses heuristics to find solutions, but I get the feeling that it still cannot compete in efficiency with a simple domain-specific grounder that feeds the grounded instances to SMT, which is then nothing more than SAT solving. Is my intuition correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. The heuristics for handling quantifiers in Z3 are not tuned for problems where universal variables range over finite/bounded domains.
In this kind of problem, using quantifiers is a good option only if a very small percentage of the instances are needed to show that a problem is unsatisfiable.

I usually suggest that users should expand this quantifiers using the programmatic API.
Here a two related posts. They contain links to Python code that implements this approach.

- [Does Z3 take a longer time to give an unsat result compared to a sat result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659098/does-z3-take-a-longer-time-to-give-an-unsat-result-compared-to-a-sat-result)
- [Quantifier Vs Non-Quantifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011478/quantifier-vs-non-quantifier)

Here is one of the code fragments:

```
VFunctionAt = Function('VFunctionAt', IntSort(), IntSort(), IntSort())

s = Solver()
s.add([VFunctionAt(V,S) >= 0 for V in range(1, 5) for S in range(1, 9)])
print s
```

In this example, I'm essentially encoding `forall V in [1,4] S in [1,8] VFunctionAt(V,S) >= 0`.

Finally, your encoding `(assert (distinct (f o1 o1) (f o1 o2) .... (f o8 o7) (f o8 o8))` is way more compact than expanding the quantifier 4096 times. However, even if we use a naive encoding (just expand the quantifier 4096 times), it is stil faster to solve the expanded version.

Comment: Thanks Leonardo, but I still have a question about this. Is it not possible to simple tell Z3: ground all the quantifiers for a given domain? That would be something that is not so hard to implement, and it would be a very useful feature because users are not required to write custom grounders but simply can input the quantified theory into Z3. Thanks.

Comment: No, it is not possible to do that in the current version. I agree with you this is not hard to implement, and is very useful for users quantifying over finite domains. This item has been on the TODO list for quite some time. It can be implemented as a tactic in Z3. That is, it can be implemented independently of other features. We are accepting external contributions (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/blog/2012/11/19/external-contrib.html). It would be great if someone could do it. Interested?

Comment: Is this answer still valid in 2023 or does z3 now have efficient heuristics for quantifiers over small finite domains?